# How to create and copy templates in the war file using ant

Tags: java, ant, war

I'm working on apache freemarker with jersey, we are gaving .ftl templates in template folder, when i trying to create a war file with template its not creating.

```
<target name="war" depends="clean,compile,copy-resources">
    <war destfile="${dist}/sample.war" webxml="WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
        <webinf dir="WEB-INF" includes="**/log4j.properties"></webinf>
        <lib dir="${lib}"/>
        <classes dir="${build}"/>
        <templates dir="${templates}"/>
    </war>      
</target>
```

When build this code it is saying

```
war doesn't support the nested "templates" element.
```

class and lib folder is adding but template folder not created in war file.

Thanks,
Praveen R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create and copy the template folder use below code

```
<copy todir="${templates}">
```

To add this folder to war file use this code

```
<webinf dir="WEB-INF" includes="**/log4j.properties,templates/"></webinf>
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [war Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html), and see the example in that page.
However you should use `zipfileset` to include your .ftl files in the war, here is how it should look like:

```
<zipfileset dir="${home.dir}/PATH_TO_FTL" includes="**/*.ftl" />
```